How can the intersection number of a primary decomposition be counted?
I'm just noticing that, if $I\subset R$ is an ideal of a commutative, noetherian ring $R$, some prime ideals can be found from either the primary decomposition of $\sqrt{I}$, or the radical ideals of the primary ideals in the decomposition of $I$. More formally:
$$[I=\bigcap_{i}P_i]\wedge [P_i\text{ primary}]\Rightarrow \sqrt{P_i}\text{ is prime}$$
To use this fact about decompositions to find prime ideals, however, it is necessary to count the number of intersections in the (irredundant) primary decomposition of an arbitrary ideal $I$: say we define $\sharp:2^R\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to be
$$\sharp\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nP_i\right)=n$$
For $P_i$ primary and irredundant. Then, for every ideal $I\subseteq R$, $\sharp(I)\in\mathbb{N}$ is well-defined, since $R$ is noetherian. It follows that the set of all prime ideals of $R$ is denoted by:
$$\mathfrak{P}=\{\sqrt{I}\subset R|\sharp(I)=1\}$$
But, defined in this way, $\sharp(I)$ needs to be computed after knowing the primary decomposition of $I$, which can be hard to compute itself.
Is there another definition of $\sharp(I)$ that doesn't require calculating primary decompositions? A special condition for the case $\sharp(I)=1$ seems to be:
$$\sharp(I)=1\Leftrightarrow I\text{ is primary}$$
